# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' while using re.match

Tags: python, regex

I need to compare the first element of two different files *after* a certain phrase. So far I have this:

```
import re

data1 = ""
data2 = ""
first = re.match(r".*Ignore until after this:(?P<data1>.*)", firstlist[0])
second = re.match(r".*Ignore until after this:(?P<data2>.*)", secondarray[0])
data1 = first.group('data1')
data2 = second.group('data2')

if data1 == data2:
  #rest of the code...
```

I want to ignore everything up to a certain point, and then save the rest into the variable. I do something almost identical to this earlier in the script and it works. However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
File "myfile.py", line [whatever line it is], in <module>  
data1 = first.group('data1')  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why isn't `re.match` isn't working properly with first and second?

#### EDIT

As per suggestion, I've changed `[\s\S]*` to `.*`.

EDIT 2: This is what the input looks like (NOT like in the comment below):

```
Random text

More random text

Even more random text

Ignore until after this:

Meaningful text, keep this

...and everything else...

...until the end of the file here
```

That's really basically all it is: a string of text that needs to be saved from after a certain point

Comment: Why are you using `[\s\S]*`? Since `\S` is the inverse of `\s`, you may as well just use `.*` and be done with it (with `re.DOTALL`).

Comment: I tried it that way as well and got the same error, the \s\S was just kind of grasping at straws, trying to change anything I could that might possibly be causing the problem, just forgot to switch it back

Comment: We'll need to see input samples then. You don't need to 'declare' `data1` and `data2`, btw.

Comment: The files are mostly just like this format (unfortunately I can't use the real ones, since it's for a project):

some text
some more text

Comment: That is **not** enough information for us to reproduce your problem, let alone help you.

Comment: Sorry my computer's being stupid and not letting me edit the comment with proper formatting, I'm going to add input example to the question

Comment: For future reference for people reading this, ignore my second comment above here, the formatting in comments wouldn't let me make it correctly, the formatting is correct in the example in the question edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably just having issues because of the newlines in your file. As Martijn Pieters pointed out in the comments to your questions, you can use the flag re.DOTALL to capture everything. So with a file like so, (named `tmp` in this example)

```
Random text

More random text

Even more random text

Ignore until after this:

Meaningful text, keep this

...and everything else...

...until the end of the file here
```

You could do something like this

```
with open('tmp') as f:
  first = re.match(r'.*Ignore until after this:(?P<data1>.*)', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
  print(first.group('data1'))
```

which gives

```
Meaningful text, keep this

...and everything else...

...until the end of the file here
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up solving the problem in a way w/o regex that is pretty specific to the layout with my project (so probably won't be helpful to others to post) but I'm marking this as the answer because that was originally the problem I was running into :)

Answer (score 0):

The dot '.' character in regular expressions matches any character except a newline.  So if you have your entire file as a single string, then the regular expression is matching up to the first new line, then trying to match your phrase against the start of the next line.  When this fails, it returns a NoneType.

See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953406/python-regular-expression-matching-multiple-lines-re-dotall).

Comment: thanks, the problem is it wouldn't be the first newline. I originaly had [\s\S]* instead of .* to just match everything including newlines, but I ran into the same problem.